# Get-ADUser not returning all possible AD attributes when specifying all properties

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've run into a case where specific properties are not enumerated when using
`Get-ADUser -Properties *`. For example the following code does not list the
`msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` property even though it exists and I can specify it as a
`-Properties` argument, have it return, and can process its value.

```
# Does not return msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed
Get-ADUser username -Properties *

# This works to get the msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed attribute returned
Get-ADUser username -Properties msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed

# If I really want all properties and this one
# I have to specify it alongside *
Get-ADUser username -Properties *, msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed
```

This isn't just a case of the property being omitted from the display, I need to explicitly state the `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` property or else it simply isn't available on the resulting object.

I already know filtering on `Properties *` isn't a good idea in most cases, but I'm curious about why **all** AD DS attributes are not enumerated when this is precisely what I am asking the cmdlet to do.

This question is asking about `Get-ADUser` but like most other behaviors with the `Get-ADObject` cmdlets I assume this behavior extends to most, if not all, of them.

Comment: Not an answer, but related: https://blogs.msmvps.com/richardsiddaway/2012/03/25/attributes-returned-by-the-cmdlets/

Comment: Nice enumeration of additional properties that don't return when using `-Properties *`, thanks for that

Comment: Also just wondering, if you did `Get-ADObject username -Properties *` is there any difference?

Comment: Yes, I get 53 properties returned by using `Get-ADObject` instead of 113 when using `Get-ADUser` (both specifying `-Properties *`. So I get even less information by default. Also, `Get-ADObject username` didn't work for me (errored with `Cannot find an object with identity`), so I filtered on my `SamAccountName` as a test.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest `Get-AdUser username -Properties * | Select *` does the property show up in this list?

Comment: No, the property doesn't exist on the returned `ADUser` unless I explicitly add it to the `-Properties` parameter.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest - Though I don't have a backing source with me, but, I'm pretty sure that [msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed being a Constructed Attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223384.aspx) is not displayed by default. In my experience, these are displayed only when you individually query them. [The attributes which you get from the cmdlet for a particular object type are the set of attributes that govern the creation and update of those objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223126.aspx#gt_fd49ea36-576c-4417-93bd-d1ac63e71093). Please check if it helps.

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. Still leaves open the question of how to return ***all*** possible attributes for inspection, regardless of the attribute type. I did [find this article](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/04/25/pstip-list-all-active-directory-constructed-attributes/) for how to use an `-LDAPFilter` on `Get-ADObject` to list all constructed attributes defined in the schema, of which the returned attribute names could be inserted into the `Get-ADObject` cmdlets' `-Properties` parameter, but I am on vacation this week and won't be able to test this until next week.

Comment: I'm also not able to find a direct source stating this, but based on inferences from several other articles/blog posts I think you are correct in that Constructed Attributes are omitted when `-Properties *` is specified, unless you include any Constructed Attributes as part of the `-Properties` array.

Comment: I keep finding good info, last comment until I write up a proper answer, but the [Determining an Attribute Type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/determining-an-attribute-type) and [System-Flags attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ADSchema/a-systemflags) docs from Microsoft shed some light, indicating the different attribute types and how they relate to how `systemFlags` is set on each attribute type. My suspicion is that the AD cmdlets don't implicitly return attributes where `Constructed` (`4`) or `Non-Replicated` (`2`) is flagged on that attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, there are multiple types of attributes on an `ADObject` - `Default`, `Extended`, and `Constructed` are some examples of these.

`Default` properties are returned on all `ADObject` queries matching a specific type of `ADObject` (`ADUser` has its own set of default properties, `ADGroup` has it's own set, etc.)

`Extended` properties are not returned by default but are implicitly enumerable static attributes on an `ADObject`.

`Constructed` attributes are not static properties but are calculated based on the values of other attributes belonging to an `ADObject`. I could not find any info on this, but I imagine that enumerating all `Constructed` attributes can be an expensive operation since the values are computed, and as such need to be **explicitly** requested via the `-Properties` parameter of the `Get-ADObject` cmdlets.

This all seems to be related to the `systemFlags` attribute on an `ADObject`, which is where the attribute types are set. From my testing, attributes with either the `Constructed (4)` or `Non-Replicated (2)` flag need to be explicitly specified to be returned from the RSAT cmdlets.

### Sources

[msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223384.aspx)

[List All Constructed Attributes on ADObject using an LDAP Filter](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/04/25/pstip-list-all-active-directory-constructed-attributes/)

[Determining an Attribute Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ad/determining-an-attribute-type)

[SystemFlags Attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ADSchema/a-systemflags)

Comment: Here's a complementary post related to this issue: https://superuser.com/questions/1738998/is-msds-userpasswordexpirytimecomputed-a-hidden-member/1739099#1739099. Thank you for the answer and question here @Blender +1 x2

Answer (score 6):

The following code should return ALL attributes of an AD User (all properties of the ObjectClass=user):

```
$properties = Get-ADObject -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE).SchemanamingContext -Filter {name -eq "User"} -Properties MayContain,SystemMayContain |
  Select-Object @{name="Properties";expression={$_.maycontain+$_.systemmaycontain}} |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty Properties

Get-ADUser -Identity username -Properties $properties | fl $properties
```

Firstly it retrieves and saves all user properties into an array and then secondly the properties array is used with Get-ADUser to retrieve all the properties for a single user (in this example).